# Why doesn't sublime text 2 editor see the font?

Tags: fonts, sublimetext2

I have installed some old-fashoined DOS-style fonts recently (in ttf format). Now I am trying to set them as a default font in sublime text, passing the corresponding font name via "font_face" param in user settings file, but it seems that maybe I am spelling the name incorrectly, or the font somehow isn't recognized by ST2.. I have tried writing the font name differently, but no luck.

So, is there a way to know the exact font name I should pass to this parameter? How does ST2 searches installed fonts by giving a string to font_face parameter?
I have uploded fonts [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/943359/dosfonts.zip).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need add these to user-settings:

```
{
  "font_face": "keyrus",
  "font_size":  12,
  "font_options": ["directwrite"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your font file: keyrusMedium.ttf
Double click on it in Windows (I use XP) and it will open a window with the font details and some exmaple text in the font.

Beside 'Typeface name' is the name you need to use in your ST2 settings file.

For this font it is keyrus

I tried it in my ST2 settings file and it worked

**Update**: Apologies - it didn't actually work. The font changed and I thought it looked like the keyrus font, but it turned out it was some default that ST2 uses.

I have had a further look at your font files and the only "script" in the font file is "cyrillic"

Most of my other fonts have "western" as one of the "scripts" in the font file. So I am wondering if ST2 is looking for the "western" script in the font file and it doesn't exist so it doesn't display the font.

I have tried a few fonts I have and all work if they have "western" as a script. I tried one that only had "arabic" as the script and it didn't work.

Out of my depth about how you'd convert the font file to include the "western" script.

Comment: strange, I have tried entering keyrus from the beginning, and I can clearly see, that ST2 do not use this font. Here's the picture taken from my ST2 settings, and, as you can see, it uses some kind of different font instead. http://i.imgur.com/BPWS9am.png EDIT: I must also note, that I use windows 7.